# what's the best to use to android with xml

Tags: android

I'm working in android with web services I just confused between the xml parser way what the diffrence between the httpclient and the xmlpullparser SAXParser and what's the best to use with xml webservices for uploading updating and parsing the data ??

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the built-in parsers is Simple XML (http://simple.source forge.net). I really like it for working with XML on Android because you don't have to worry about low level parser logic. Plus, it's quite lightweight.